Hibernate DuplicateMappingException with snake and camelcases. Spring
Migrating some big project from Play to Spring. There is many legacy models in which present separated id of relation nearby.
private Long userId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
private User user;

I know what best of all probably to erase all direct id-field calls. But it will be a lot of monkeybusiness which is preferably to move on refactoring part of migration.
All DB table columns in snake_case.
currently my configs is
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy

The actual problem is that I have this exception:

Table [user_stuff_info] contains physical column name [user_id] referred to by multiple logical column names: [user_id], [userId]

Hibernate is considering user field as logical user_id, I can annotate userId field with name param like this
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;

and error will be gone. But I will have to go around all existing data model, and it's pretty big. Sooner or later it will be "cleaned up". But I have to raise the context asap. Is there a way to config spring boot application "3.2.1" to resolve this collision, or there is no shortcuts, and only way I have is to clean this dirt at this point?
